# Insert thumb image in List View in Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

I am using List View Template in Intel XDK in my project i want to use thumbnail of images in each list. Is there any workaround? As I am new in HTML development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add code within the `<li>` element to create `<img>` element. Here is example code to create a custom list with image thumbnail + text: [Custom ListView](https://github.com/krisrak/appframework-templates/blob/master/documentation/ListViewApp.md#listview-with-custom-list)

```
<style>
    #afui #listview .list li {padding:10px 20px 10px 10px}
    .list-image {float:left;width:50px;height:50px}
    .list-text {margin-left:60px;min-height:50px}        
</style>
```

custom `<li>`:

```
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <a href="#item1">
                <img class="list-image" src="data/male_user_icon.svg" />
                <div class="list-text"><b>username1</b><br>Placeholder text for this list item 1.</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```